# I have created an Int array from a Char array now the values don't match

Tags: java, arrays

Ok so when I use this code instead of a 9999 I get 57 for each 9? Pretty confused new to Java any help would be appreciated!!

```
public int[] getNumber(){

    String newNum;

    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

    System.out.println( "Please enter four digits" );
    newNum = input.nextLine();
    char[] list = newNum.toCharArray();
    int[] numArray = new int[newNum.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < newNum.length(); i++){
        numArray[i] = list[i];
    }

    return numArray;
}
```

Comment: That is because 9 is treated as a character which has int value 57 in ASCII. You need to parse the characters or the string as number and not just cast/store its numeric charactervalue which will be different from its numeric value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. 57 is the [integer value of the char '9'](http://www.asciitable.com/). So it's expected. If you want the numeric value of the char, use

```
numArray[i] = list[i] - '0';
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, is there other instances where '0' can be used to get numerical values?

Comment: '0' is just another syntax for `((char) 48)`. You must understand that for computers, chars are just numbers like other numbers. The Java language allows typing '0' instead of ((char) 48) because it's much more intuitive and readable. But it's in fact a 2-bytes long numner which has the value 48. '1' is 49, '2' is 50, etc.